# Constans variable assigned by function and used to create array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, constants

I use Visual Studio 2012

My target:

User give array size -> function return data to const variable  -> and create array.
It is possible?

Here is my code snippets:

```
const int user_get_array_size()
{
int a;
bool blokada;

do
{
    cout << "Podaj wielkość tablicy: ";
    cin >> a;

    //Jeśli cin nie mógł zapisać danych do inta.
    //Lub wielkość tablicy mniejsza od 1? (Po co nam analizować coś co ma )
    if(cin.fail() || a < 2)
    {
        blokada = true;


        //Czyszczenie Cina z syfów.
        //Cin wchodzi char by char
        //while(cin)
        //{
            cin.clear(); //Czyszczenie CINA
        //}

        cin.ignore();

        system("CLS");
        cout << "Wielkość tablicy musi być liczą wiekszą od 1 \n(Wkońcu ten program ma coś analizować.) \n";
    }
    else
    {
        blokada = false;
    }
}
while(blokada);



return a;
}


const int w_array = user_get_array_size();

int tablica[ w_array ];
```

I got error : Expression must have constant value?

Where is my fault?

Comment: You need a compile time constant (or a C++11 `constexpr`) for the dimensions of an array. In this case, your `const int` is only constant in the sense that it cannot be modified. It is not a compile time constant. Have a look at `std::vector` or C++14 `std::dynarray`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Or C++14 VLAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initialize `const int w_array` like the following:

```
const int w_array = 100;
```

Then there would be no problem as `100` is known at compile time. However, you initialize `w_array` with the return from the function which is only known at run time. Therefore, you cannot use `w_array` in the array declaration because the value needs to be known at compile time.

The easiest way to fix your code is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> tablica(w_array);
```

Note that `const` is tricky in C++. When you initialize it with a literal, it can be used in contexts that require constant expressions. When you initialize it with a value only known at run time, it is a read-only variable but it cannot be used in contexts that require constant expressions.

Also, some of the problems have been solved with `constexpr` functions in C++11. However, visual studio does not support this yet, and since your code requires input from the user, you would not be able to use it anyway.